# 7 segment display

Tags: power-supply, raspberry-pi, 7segmentdisplay

i recently bought a 7 segment display for research purposes. I have connected this to the raspberry pi and i got an output. The thing is that, the segment has 4 digit display and all the displays show the same output. Is there any other alternative way where i could display different outputs in each of the display. i have posted the picture of the display and also the pin configuration. Also can i connect the 3.3v pin to gpio pin of the raspberry pi and resist the flow of voltage? i got the product from the below link https://www.amazon.in/Delson-Electronics-Digit-Segment-Anode/dp/B076HV47XF

[image]

[image]

Comment: Each segment has two sides (they are LEDs.) However, all of the LEDs for each digit are tied together on one side. Then all four of the "A" LEDs have another side tied together. This is why you get the same digit on every one of the displays. To get different values you need to "multiplex" the unit. This means that you present some setting for A-H, and then activate D1 ONLY. Do that for a while, then turn off D1, set up a different setting for A-H, then activate D2 ONLY. Etc. Once you get done with this for D4, you repeat for D1 again, and so on. Read up on multiplexing 7-seg displays.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Multiplexing.

The eye has a response time, this means if you flash the LED very fast, from your eye you will see that is on.

This LED panel is designed so that each 7 segment digit is "flashed" one after the other, from the eye view it will look like they are on.

This method is used to avoid having to use too many input / output on the controller.

To do so, you need to quickly switch on the first segment for a few milliseconds with the correct value to display. Then you switch it off, and you switch on the next one with another value and so forth for the other two.

It's basically the same way a TV or most led display works.

[Here is a link that explains it](https://tams.informatik.uni-hamburg.de/applets/hades/webdemos/45-misc/50-displays/multiplexed-display.html)